# Using margin within flowframe

Tags: multicolumn, layout, flowfram

I'm working on an A3 landscape document, which is divided into several blocks with different size. Hence, I come up to use flowfram to define all blocks. However, I need some margin for the text within the flowframe because some flowframes have backgroundcolors and the text is normally aligned directly to the border of the flowframe. Is there a possibility to set a margin within a flowframe? Is it manageable with the borders of flowframes? Or is there another approach?

Comment: Thank you for that information. However, that sounds not very intuitive. Maybe I'll use a background for the whole document or add some color boxes or a static frame? I'll try

Comment: Ah, you want a border.  The best solution is probably to add a slightly larger static frame behind (defined before) the flow frame, or possibly a tikzpicture in overlay mode.